# Can't start remote GUI programs using terminal on Rhel.7

Tags: terminal, redhat-enterprise-linux, gui, xterm

Can't start remote GUI programs like gedit, Firefox, and more GUI on RHEL.7 using terminal directly.
how to open that direct,
not as ssh.
XTerm required for that?
or what application is required for getting GUI?
Kindly suggest me what to do?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this one's a bit unclear, but options are:

- VNC witch is essentially remote desktop
- Yes, Xterm can open GUIs but I am not sure if you want the GUI to be opened on the server or the client because by just opening it like you normally would on you PC but with ssh you just send a instruction to open a GUI, so it will open on the server. But if you're a good enough programmer you probably can write a script to open a GUI on the server, get it and put it on the client's screen.
- IPMI, but you need a server motherboard with IPMI ethernet port.

Comment: when echo $xterm, is given, the output is xterm -256color......it means xterm is already installed in the server but why can't start GUI programs?

Comment: Are you trying to open the GUI via ssh or directly from the computer? I think that, with ssh, it opens the GUI on the server you control via ssh.

Comment: how to open the GUI directly from the computer.  pl see this output Caused by: java.awt.AWTException: Exception: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero occurred while creating cursor CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(Cursor.java:362)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(XToolkit.java:1435)
    ... 10 more

Comment: Have you specified the cursor position/size?

Comment: no, how to specify

Comment: What exact command did you use?

Comment: ssh -X root@ip address